# What causes "A disk read error occurred, Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart"?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a virtual machine containing Windows XP SP3.

When I resized the VHD file (and the embedded partition), and tried booting, I got:

```
A disk read error occurred
Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart
```

Some notes:

- `FixBoot` and `FixMBR` don't help.
- `ChkDsk` doesn't help.
- The partition is indeed active.
- The partition starts at sector 63 (it also did so *before* the problem) of cylinder 1, head 1, and is marked as type 0x07 (NTFS)
- My host OS reads the VHD and the partition **completely fine**
- I'm interested in knowing the **cause** rather than the *fix*. So "re-format the disk", "reinstall Windows", etc. aren't valid solutions.

  It's a virtual machine after all... I have nothing to lose, so I don't care about fixing it.
  I just want to know what's causing this problem, in case I run into it again on a physical machine (which I have done before).

---

#### More info:

I made a sample VHD file illustrating (almost) the same problem which you can download [here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/fqhrjq).

To reproduce the problem:

- Download the file (it's *highly* compressed, be careful!), and try booting it in VirtualBox (or some other VM). Notice that you'll be told "Error loading operating system". (While the error is different, it's the same issue.)
- Now try mounting the VHD in Windows's Disk Management, and running `BootSect.exe /NT60 X: /MBR`, where `X:` is the drive letter of the mounted volume. (The location of the tool is likely to be `C:\boot\bootsect.exe`, but if it's not there on your system, then you'll need to find it somewhere else...) Now un-mount it, and try booting. The boot should now proceed correctly. (Although it won't find Hal.dll, at least you know it's working.)
- Now do the same thing as the last step, but use `/NT52` instead of `/NT60`. You will now be greeted with the first error -- indicating that the Windows XP loader *doesn't like the disk*.
  So my question is: **Why?**

Comment: @Moab: What you said makes no sense. :( I resized it on my host system, and even if I had done it on my guest system, it's not like the software would be behaving differently...

Comment: @Moab: Are you assuming it's dynamically sized? Because it's definitely a fixed-size drive... and like I said, it's fine in my host OS, so it's not like it's unreadable or something.

Comment: I would have assumed that resizing the disk would have modified the some vital information in the disk that the OS uses to work out the partition it needs to boot from, but as you've tried the main tools to repair that kind of thing it may be something in the OS itself.  When does the error occur?  Is it immediately after the VM starts up or can you get to the Boot Menu screen where you select safe mode or normal boot?

Comment: Another thing to try would be to create a new (larger) vhd and within the VM use Clonezilla to copy the old partition to it and see what it does then.

Answer (score 2):

The cause is either that bootloader is calling the BIOS to read other disk sectors and that call is failing, or the bootloader does not consider the partition table valid.

If I am not mistaken, when Windows formats a disk, doesn't it create a small partition at the very end of it, or leave an unpartitioned area there?  Did your resize utility recreate that?  Sounds silly but this might be the reason why it is complaining.  Weird, but I wouldn't put it past Windows (and possibly something in newer versions) to have such a quirk.

Comment: I tried leaving a small unpartitioned area at the end (10 MB -- I remember XP is usually 8 MB), but it didn't work.

Comment: I have just done it for my VHD. I resized the partition and left 20MB free unallocated space. It worked. Thanks, get +1.

Answer (score 2):

File-systems are intricate, complex, finicky things. For example, an old copy of Partition Magic complains about some little numeric inconsistency or something about the partitions on one of my disks while Windows (XP) and Easeus Partition Master and such all chug along without issue. Even an old copy of Norton Disk Editor doesn’t complain about that disk.

The fact is that there are a lot little things that can go wrong, or worse, that can “go *not* wrong” yet still be incorrect (i.e., an incorrect value could show no symptoms).

What likely happened was that when you resized the VHD file, the tool that you used had a bug and did not (correctly?) update a field somewhere in the file-systems of the disk (partition table? boot-record? boot-sector? NTFS meta-files?)

As others have pointed out, the error you are getting is usually a **BIOS** error as opposed to an OS error. What is likely happening is that the field that was not correctly updated was early in the disk (e.g., in the boot-record or partition table) so when the VM BIOS tries to read the disk, it is finding incorrect/inconsistent values and throwing an exception. You did not mention what kind of resizing you did. Did you shrink or expand it?

My hypothesis is that you resized it *down*, and the BIOS is reading the partition table and trying to read beyond the disk (to non-existent sectors) because the size of the disk was not properly updated.

As for the host, I would surmise that the reason that it can correctly read the disk is because the software that mounts the VHD file is somehow masking the error. After all, to the host, the “disk” is not a real disk and is actually just a (`.vhd`) file, while to the guest, the disk is supposedly a real, physical disk. As such, the host can error-correct problems that the guest cannot.

You can check to see if there is an updated version of the tool or use a boot disk like CloneZilla (or find a copy of PTEdit) to run in the VM and examine the “disk” from within the host.

Comment: I just ran another partition manager on it, and like the ones before, it didn't report a single error. So confused... (also, something else that's weird: if I boot the *working* disk as a Primary Slave instead of a Primary Master, I get the same error...)

Comment: I just confirmed that it isn't a *partition* issue, but a *disk* issue. The problem happens when I use [VHDResize](http://vmtoolkit.com/files/folders/converters/entry87.aspx) to resize it... the partition inside is left untouched, but the disk is resized to a size greater than that of the partition.

Comment: Looking at the table you added to the question, it looks like the partition remains the same, but the disk is reduced to only 1,147 sectors more than the partition. The values in relation to the partition remain unchanged, so what is likely to be happening is that some of the meta-data in the `.vhd` file that controls the size of the disk itself is incorrect. Any tools run from within the VM (including the BIOS) would be limited to whatever the VM tells it about the disk.

Comment: Oh, so you think the VHD itself is corrupted (even though the contents are fine)? That's an interesting idea... I haven't come across any errors while mounting it in Windows, but maybe that's just luck...

Comment: In addition to the contents of the disk itself, the `.vhd` file contains meta-data *about* the disk. Perhaps VHDResize is not updating a field when it performs the modifications. The specs for the VHD format are available, so it doesn’t need to be reverse-engineered; so maybe it’s just a bug.     *>I haven't come across any errors while mounting it in Windows*   Can you mount it and then format and fill it up without errors?

Comment: Yeah I've looked at the specs before, I know what you're talking about... but I just did a full format and it went fine. And what's funny is that, after I formatted it and tried booting it (empty), it said "BOOTMGR is missing, Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart". So obviously the MBR is intact as well... (why is it a Vista-style MBR? Not sure, maybe I booted it with Windows 7 once... I'll look into that next...)

Comment: Actually, I just (magically?!) fixed it... I ran `bootsect /nt60 F: /mbr` where F: was the volume, and somehow that made it boot... so baffled right now.

Comment: Are you formatting and running `bootsect` from inside the VM or outside?

Comment: I did both from outside (by mounting the VHD with Disk Management).

Comment: I take it that the VM is configured as `XP` right? Maybe when you formatted it from the host, it changed the signatures in the disk which the emulated XP guest could not read. What happens if you change the guest to `7`?

Comment: Let me see if I can make a copy of the disk that can simply show the boot menu, without any Windows files... maybe I can just post a sample that way.

Comment: Okay, I managed to make a sample [here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/fqhrjq). It shows the same problem, except with a different error this time ("Error loading operating system") -- but if you run `BootSect.exe /NT60 F: /MBR` on it (assuming F: is the drive), then it'll load boot.ini correctly, and say Hal.dll was not found. And if you change `/NT60` to `/NT52`, it should again tell you "Error loading operating system"... and so the question is why is that happening?

Comment: Well like I said, the guest OS VM is configured for Windows XP but the disk has been modified by the Windows 7 host which changed the boot record. When you ran `bootsect /nt52` you changed it back to the XP boot record. You may want to edit the VM’s BIOS to make sure that the disk is set correctly since it has been changed.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment. I don't understand what that means though -- if I change the boot record back to XP's, then shouldn't it boot fine? Why do I get an error?

Comment: I'll give you the bounty since your answer provided the best clues, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I see is that after resizing the VHD, some incompatibility exists between what the BIOS thinks it knows about the hard disk and the disk itself.

Another possibility is that the free space on the disk is too small or too fragmented for Windows to boot. Sometimes defragmenting a disk with this error makes it bootable.

[EDIT]

According to your added info, you have drastically reduced the VHD from 127GB to 1.5GB, so there might not be enough space for the pagefile. The resizer you have used may have been too aggressive, or it may have moved such unmovable Windows system files and therefore rendered the disk unbootable.

For proper operation, Windows needs quite a lot of free space on the disk, with some of it contiguous (for at least the pagefile).

I think that the correct procedure should have been from the 127GB VHD to turn off in XP the pagefile and system restore, clear the Recycle bin, defragment the disk with a defragmenter that can consolidate used space at the top (or free space at the bottom), then do the resize leaving free space that is several times the defined RAM size.

With this procedure you might have ended up with a viable and bootable disk to start with.

Sometimes these problems clear up with repeated reboot, maybe by Windows finally managing to rearrange the disk to its liking.

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering what the incompatibility might be.

Comment: I have added some more guesses.

Comment: Page files aren't even used until the the kernel has *finished* loading. The problem here is that *boot.ini* isn't even loaded properly in the first place, let alone even *starting* the kernel... the problem here simply *can't* be due to this.

Comment: What Windows does exactly during boot remains a mystery. All I can say is that I have seen similar behavior in XP computers that have over-filled the system drive. My solution was always to reformat and install, so I have never found out exactly what the problem is.

Comment: That's what I mentioned yesterday. I doubt though if Mehrdad has even tried it, there is various stuff written at boot as can be seen in tracing tools like Process Monitor and Windows Performance Analyzer. @harrymc: As you said `mistery` I would suggest you to do at least a Process Monitor boot log, because the booting sequence is not a mystery at all... :)

Comment: @harrymc: Ah, regarding that part of the answer, check Mehrdad's last comment to my answer. That clarifies that space is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│   Sectors:     3149824          Disk Signature:  0xEE3EEE3E                 │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│Pos Idx Type/Name Size Boot Hide  Start Sector  Total Sectors  DL Vol Label  │
├─── ─── ───────── ──── ──── ──── ────────────── ────────────── ── ───────────┤
│ 1   1  07-NTFS   1.5G  Yes  No              63      3,148,677 F: <None>     │
╘═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╛

3,148,677 / 3,149,824 = 0.999636 = 1 - 0.000364

1.5G * 0.000364 = 0.000546G
```

There only seem to be about 546 KB free, it might be possible that it can't write a file upon boot.

Comment: I think you're taking the "1.5G" too literally. I'm pretty sure it's rounding/truncating.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Then, still. What if it needs to expand the page file during boot? Expand it a few G and see what happens. If it's still broken then some essential bits were gone or the VHD is corrupt; if it works, you didn't leave it enough room. You might say that I take it too literally; so, please also take a look at the drive's properties using Windows Explorer (mount it in the disk manager) which should give the *exact* free count...

Comment: You *do* know that the page file is only used *after* the kernel has finished booting, right? (i.e. about the same time as BootExecute is being run.) This thing isn't even *loading boot.ini*.

Comment: If you're interested, I've uploaded a sample with instructions in my update. (It might take a bit of time to reproduce it, though.)

Comment: I'm rather wondering if you have reproduced my suggestion? I'm on a school project now so might not be able to look into this the first days...

Comment: Which suggestion? If you're referring to the free space one, that's 100% wrong because the boot loader doesn't even know *which OS* to boot at this point, let alone which page file. But if you're busy then don't worry about it, thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: @Mehrdad: And how did you came to that conclusion?

Comment: Tom: You'll see if you download the VHD I posted. There's *nothing* on that drive other than a boot loader (i.e. no registry, no kernel, no page file settings, not even a hal.dll... *nothing*), so the existence of a page file isn't exactly exactly relevant (see the [NT startup process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_startup_process#Session_Manager)... notice that page file creation is *waaaay* later than kernel loading)... and besides, how would that explain the fact that it works correctly when I use bootsect /nt60?!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Adding another and somewhat different answer.)</sub>

You say that booting with the NT52 boot-sector does not work, but that NT60 does.

The difference may be in the boot process. NT52 is the XP boot that uses NTLDR, while NT60 is the Vista method that uses Bootmgr.

NTLDR uses the boot.ini file to locate hard drives and partitions. It consults the computer's firmware (BIOS) to find out which hard drive is considered to be drive zero, then looks at the partition table on that drive to find out which partition is number one. Once it knows the location of the partition it can then find the Windows\system32 folder of the OS it has been asked to start.

Bootmgr consults the BCD file in the Boot folder for the information it needs to find for the correct drive and partition, but it does not use the firmware to find the hard drive, or the partition table to find the partition. Instead it uses the unique Disk Signature in the MBR of a hard drive and the partition offset (starting sector) of a partition.

Apparently while resizing the disk you have destroyed an element that is used for the NTLDR boot process but is not used by Bootmgr.
This could be the BIOS, in the sense that the information it holds about the hard disk
is no longer correct, such as the number of cylinders or sectors, or something in boot.ini itself.

In addition, bootsect updates the volume boot code, not the master boot code. The master boot code is part of the master boot record (MBR) and there's only one per physical disk. The volume boot code is part of the volume boot record and there's one per volume. It may have been that with
your tries at making the disk bootable, some incompatibility has crept in between the two that requires better knowledge than mine of the boot process to analyze.

As Bootmgr does not use the BIOS or boot.ini, it apparently manages to use the MBR and to boot.

Comment: FYI: `bootmgr` isn't even on the disk (nor is `boot\BCD`, nor is anything else Vista-related)... you can check this by downloading my example, and opening it with something (e.g. 7-zip). The *only* Vista-related thing is whatever the boot *sector* has, because of bootsect.exe... that's all.

Comment: Both the NTLDR and Bootmgr boot codes only set up the environment used for invoking the NTLDR and Bootmgr programs. I would theorize (guess) that either (1) If Bootmgr is missing, the NT60 boot code fails-back to NTLDR but does a better job of setting up the environment for it than the NT52 code, or (2) The NT60 code in your XP bootsect is still not the Vista version but is still an improvement over NT52. I would expect that (1) would rather cause a Bootmgr missing message, so believe more in (2).

Comment: Huh, I was actually under the impression that (1) is likelier than (2)... interesting...

Comment: Both are equally likely for now. You could maybe test this by copying bootmgr and a Boot folder from Vista and deleting ntldr, to see if the NT60 boot can succeed. But this is just guesswork on my part (never tried these games).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. xp with the same error. bootsect /nt52 wouldn't fix the problem. I cloned the drive out and cloned it back in, and presto- it boots. The lesson is that you have to be an expert in partitioning to pinpoint the problem. the rest of us have to resort to hacking around and whatnot. someone on the internet said that these problem can be caused by a bios limit of 137gb. might be, but it actually has several causes.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, Acronis was used. I made a copy of the boot disk, then I restored it and the system started up.